# Can Tor 6.5 be configured to use the same IP for multiple requests?

Tags: security, ip-address, tor

Some sites require that the same IP address be used for certain requests in order to provide more security.  When using Tor 6.5, the IP address is changed for each request.  Is it possible to tell Tor, "Prepare to reuse the IP address from which the server will see the next request come so that I can use it when I need to"?

My research indicates that Tor used to change exit nodes every ten minutes, but I guess they figured that they could change it for every request, so now the sites that required the same IP for two operations won't let me do those operations :-(.

I am specifically talking about btc-e.com.  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Just exchange your bitcoin on the regular web, assuming you're not trying to do something shady.

Comment: Voting to close as this doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming.